# Why does `obj instanceof ConstructorFunc` still return true even if prototype is overwritten?

Tags: javascript

I've learned that in a function's prototype, a pointer to the function itself is contained in a field called `constructor`.

```
function Person(){
}
alert(Person.prototype.constructor); // function Person(){}
```

If I overwrite the function's prototype with an object literal, the constructor field is naturally lost:

```
function Person(){
}
Person.prototype = {
    name:"Sahand",
    age:24
}
alert(Person.prototype.constructor); // function Object(){[native code]}
```

But, when the prototype has been overwritten in this manner, we can still check if an object is created by the `Person` constructor:

```
var person = new Person()
alert(person instanceof Person); // true
```

How is this possible? How can `instanceof` find out that `person` was created by `Person()` when the `constructor` field of the prototype doesn't contain `Person` anymore?

Comment: Sorry Jonas, corrected. Still learning...

Comment: no worries ;) typos happen...

Answer (score 1):

> The instanceof operator tests whether an object in its prototype chain
>   has the prototype property of a constructor.

Consider this:

```js
function Person(){}

Person.prototype = {
    name:"Sahand",
    age:24
}

var person = new Person();

console.log('instanceof', person instanceof Person);
console.log('Is "person __proto__ === Person.prototype":', 
    person.__proto__ === Person.prototype);
```

But if you change `Person.prototype` after instance creation then `person instanceof Person === false` now:

```js
function Person(){}

Person.prototype = {
    name:"Sahand",
    age:24
}

var person = new Person();

Person.prototype = {};

console.log('insanceof: ', person instanceof Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause the `instance instanceof constructor` operator doesnt test `instance.prototype.constructor` but rather `constructor.prototype` in `instance.__proto__`

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)